# CakePHP 2: AclBehavior Call to a member function node() on a non-object

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0, acl

```
class User extends AppModel {
    public $actsAs = array('Acl' => array('type' => 'requester'), 'Containable');
    ...
}
```

When I try to delete a user:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function node() on a non-object in ...\AclBehavior.php on line 89
```

How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this line in your controller..?

```
public $components = array('Acl');
```